# Facing issue while trying to init the pods on project

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

I hope you all are doing well.

I'm facing issue while trying to init the pod in the project. Cocoapods is already installed in the system. XCode Dev intstall is also there, In XCode in command line the xcode version is also selected. Don't know what I'm missing. I have MacOS BigSur.

If I run pod --version command on terminal it gives me version of 1.8.4.

I'm attaching the screenshot if someone has faced this issue.

[image]

Comment: You are omitting the full error just before. But did you check the suggested links? Current version is `1.11.2`, you don't want/can't to update?

Comment: I tried the same but not able to update that.

Comment: `gem update xcodeproj` didn't work? Did you update CocoaPods?

Comment: It didnt work, however I resolve the issue, Un-Install the brew & reinstall it, after that giving me error like cant written the file on this path conflicting with some other path, so I forcefully linked the new brew path. & it worked.

Comment: Now my pod version is 1.11.2

Comment: Thanks somewhere your comment also helped to focused on the error description, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I solved it by following these steps:

1. First uninstall cocoapods with the command:

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

2. Reinstall Cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```